# Is there a solution to quit after the first input and not continue with the second input?

Tags: python, input, exit

```
active = True
while active:
    city = input("Please enter quit to stop the user input. Enter City: ")
    temp = input("Enter Temp: ")
    if city == 'quit':
        active = False
    else:
        print()
```

#Im trying to see how to quit without going to the next input.

Comment: Assuming that you don't want to take the second input just remove it or comment it from the code. If you want to do it as per some conditions use of/else condition

Comment: No that's not the issue my mistake I fixed it. I'm trying to ask the user two separate inputs until the user types quit on the first input but I'm having trouble on where to place that if statement of 'quit'. This program should accept the city name and current temperature until user inputs the word “quit” in the city name input field.

Comment: I am not clear what you are saying. But assuming that you want to take the `temp` input only if the user don't enter `quit`, you can include the `temp = input("Enter Temp: ")` in your else block. See answer for full code

Answer (score 2):

```
active = True
while active:
    city = input("Please enter quit to stop the user input. Enter City: ")
    if city == 'quit':
        active = False
    else:
        temp = input("Enter Temp: ")
        print()
```

Comment: Oh ok it makes sense now thank you for your help I appreciate it!